# Problem with connecting clock divider generated by CORE Generator to I2S design for Spartan 6

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock, clock-speed, spartan-6

I'm trying to connect clock divider generated by CORE Generator to I2S receiver and I2S transmitter on Spartan 6. The PLL_BASE is connected via ODDR2 module, as adviced. Both receiver and transmitter work when clocks are divided without block from CORE Generator.

## Code

#### clk_wiz_v3_6.vhd

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library unisim;
use unisim.vcomponents.all;

entity clk_wiz_v3_6 is
port
 (-- Clock in ports
  CLK_IN1           : in     std_logic;
  -- Clock out ports
  mclk          : out    std_logic;
  sclk          : out    std_logic;  
  -- Status and control signals
  RESET         : in     std_logic
 );
end clk_wiz_v3_6;

architecture xilinx of clk_wiz_v3_6 is
  attribute CORE_GENERATION_INFO : string;
  attribute CORE_GENERATION_INFO of xilinx : architecture is "clk_wiz_v3_6,clk_wiz_v3_6,{component_name=clk_wiz_v3_6,use_phase_alignment=false,use_min_o_jitter=false,use_max_i_jitter=false,use_dyn_phase_shift=false,use_inclk_switchover=false,use_dyn_reconfig=false,feedback_source=FDBK_AUTO,primtype_sel=PLL_BASE,num_out_clk=2,clkin1_period=10.000,clkin2_period=10.000,use_power_down=false,use_reset=true,use_locked=false,use_inclk_stopped=false,use_status=false,use_freeze=false,use_clk_valid=false,feedback_type=SINGLE,clock_mgr_type=MANUAL,manual_override=false}";
  -- Input clock buffering / unused connectors
  signal clkin1      : std_logic;
  -- Output clock buffering / unused connectors
  signal clkfbout         : std_logic;
  signal clkout0          : std_logic;
  signal clkout1          : std_logic;
  signal clkout2_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout3_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout4_unused   : std_logic;
  signal clkout5_unused   : std_logic;
  -- Unused status signals
  signal locked_unused    : std_logic;

  signal clk0obuf : std_logic;
  signal clk0bufg : std_logic;
  signal notclk0bufg : std_logic;
  signal clk1bufg : std_logic;
  signal notclk1bufg : std_logic;
  signal clk1obuf : std_logic;

begin

    notclk0bufg <= clk0bufg;
    notclk1bufg <= clk1bufg;

  -- Input buffering
  --------------------------------------
  clkin1_buf : IBUFG
  port map
   (O => clkin1,
    I => CLK_IN1);


  -- Clocking primitive
  --------------------------------------
  -- Instantiation of the PLL primitive
  --    * Unused inputs are tied off
  --    * Unused outputs are labeled unused

  pll_base_inst : PLL_BASE
  generic map
   (BANDWIDTH            => "OPTIMIZED",
    CLK_FEEDBACK         => "CLKFBOUT",
    COMPENSATION         => "INTERNAL",
    DIVCLK_DIVIDE        => 4,
    CLKFBOUT_MULT        => 29,
    CLKFBOUT_PHASE       => 0.000,
    CLKOUT0_DIVIDE       => 59,
    CLKOUT0_PHASE        => 0.000,
    CLKOUT0_DUTY_CYCLE   => 0.500,
    CLKOUT1_DIVIDE       => 118,
    CLKOUT1_PHASE        => 0.000,
    CLKOUT1_DUTY_CYCLE   => 0.500,
    CLKIN_PERIOD         => 10.000,
    REF_JITTER           => 0.010)
  port map
    -- Output clocks
   (CLKFBOUT            => clkfbout,
    CLKOUT0             => clkout0,
    CLKOUT1             => clkout1,
    CLKOUT2             => clkout2_unused,
    CLKOUT3             => clkout3_unused,
    CLKOUT4             => clkout4_unused,
    CLKOUT5             => clkout5_unused,
    -- Status and control signals
    LOCKED              => locked_unused,
    RST                 => RESET,
    -- Input clock control
    CLKFBIN             => clkfbout,
    CLKIN               => clkin1);

       ODDR2_inst : ODDR2
   generic map(
      DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
      INIT => '0',
      SRTYPE => "SYNC")
   port map (
      Q => clk0obuf,    -- 1-bit output data
      C0 => clk0bufg,       -- 1-bit clock input
      C1 => NOTclk0bufg, -- 1-bit clock input
      CE => '1',              -- 1-bit clock enable input
      D0 => '1',
      D1 => '0',
      R => '0',    -- 1-bit reset input
      S => '0'     -- 1-bit set input
   );

      ODDR2_inst2 : ODDR2
   generic map(
      DDR_ALIGNMENT => "NONE",
      INIT => '0',
      SRTYPE => "SYNC")
   port map (
      Q => clk1obuf,    -- 1-bit output data
      C0 => clk1bufg,       -- 1-bit clock input
      C1 => NOTclk1bufg, -- 1-bit clock input
      CE => '1',              -- 1-bit clock enable input
      D0 => '1',
      D1 => '0',
      R => '0',    -- 1-bit reset input
      S => '0'     -- 1-bit set input
   );

  -- Output buffering
  -------------------------------------


  clkout1_buf : BUFG
  port map
   (O   => clk0bufg, --mclk
    I   => clkout0);

  clkout2_buf : BUFG
  port map
   (O   => clk1bufg, --sclk
    I   => clkout1);

    clkout3_buf : OBUF
    port map
    (O   => mclk, --mclk
     I   => clk0obuf);

    clkout4_buf : OBUF
    port map
    (O   => sclk, --sclk
    I   => clk1obuf);

end xilinx;
```

#### i2sClocks.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity i2sClocks is
    port
     (
        clk     : in std_logic;
        lrclk   : out std_logic
    );
end i2sClocks;

architecture rtl of i2sClocks is

    signal i2sClocksDivider_i :std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin

    lrclk <= i2sClocksDivider_i(6);

   process(clk)
   begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            i2sClocksDivider_i <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(i2sClocksDivider_i) + 1);
      end if;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

#### receiver.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity i2sReceiver is
    port(
        serialClock : in std_logic;
        wordSelect  : in std_logic;
        serialData  : in std_logic;
        lastSample  : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
end i2sReceiver;

architecture rtl of i2sReceiver is

    signal currentSample_i : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal currentSampleIndex_i : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');   
    signal lastWordSelect_i : std_logic;

begin

    process(serialClock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(serialClock) then    
            currentSampleIndex_i <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(currentSampleIndex_i) + 1);

            if currentSampleIndex_i(4 downto 0) < "11000" then
                currentSample_i(to_integer(unsigned(currentSampleIndex_i(4 downto 0)))) <= serialData;
            end if;

            if (lastWordSelect_i = (not lastWordSelect_i)) then
                lastWordSelect_i <= wordSelect;

                if lastWordSelect_i = '1' then
                    currentSampleIndex_i <= (others => '0');
                end if;
            end if;

        end if;

        if falling_edge(serialClock) then
            if ((currentSampleIndex_i = "011100") or (currentSampleIndex_i = "111100")) then
                lastSample <= currentSample_i;
            end if;
        end if;

    end process;
end rtl;
```

#### transmitter.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity i2sTransmitter is
    port (
        serialClock     : in std_logic;
        wordSelect      : in std_logic;
        serialData      : out std_logic;
        lastSample      : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
end i2sTransmitter;

architecture rtl of i2sTransmitter is

    signal currentSample_i : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal currentSampleIndex_i : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');  
    signal lastWordSelect_i : std_logic;

begin

    process(serialClock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(serialClock) then

            currentSampleIndex_i <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(currentSampleIndex_i) + 1);

            if (lastWordSelect_i = (not lastWordSelect_i)) then         
                lastWordSelect_i <= wordSelect;
                if lastWordSelect_i = '1' then
                    currentSampleIndex_i <= "000001";
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;

        if falling_edge(serialClock) then
            if ((currentSampleIndex_i = "011100") or (currentSampleIndex_i = "111100")) then
                currentSample_i(23 downto 0) <= lastSample;
         end if;

            if currentSampleIndex_i(4 downto 0) < "11000" then
                serialData <= currentSample_i(to_integer(unsigned(currentSampleIndex_i(4 downto 0))));
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

#### top.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity box is
    port(   
        clk                 : in std_logic;
        reset               : in std_logic;
        adcSerial       : in std_logic;
        mclkAdc         : out std_logic;
        sclkAdc         : out std_logic;
        lrclkAdc            : out std_logic;        
        dacSerial       : out std_logic;
        mclkDac         : out std_logic;
        sclkDac         : out std_logic;
        lrclkDac            : out std_logic     
    );
end box;

architecture Behavioral of box is

    component clk_wiz_v3_6 is
    port
    (
        clk_in1         : in std_logic;   
        mclk            : out std_logic;
        sclk             : out std_logic;     
        reset          : in std_logic
    );
    end component;

    component i2sClocks is
    port
    (
        clk             : in std_logic;
        lrclk           : out std_logic
    );
    end component;

    component i2sReceiver is
    port(
        serialClock     : in std_logic;
        wordSelect      : in std_logic;
        serialData      : in std_logic;
        lastSample      : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    component i2sTransmitter is
    port(
        serialClock     : in std_logic;
        wordSelect      : in  std_logic;
        serialData      : out std_logic;
        lastSample      : in std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal mclk_i   : std_logic;
    signal sclk_i   : std_logic;
    signal lrclk_i  : std_logic;

    signal dacSerial_i: std_logic;  

    signal sample_i : std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

begin

    mclkAdc <= mclk_i;
    sclkAdc <= sclk_i;
    lrclkAdc <= lrclk_i;

    mclkDac <= mclk_i;
    sclkDac <= sclk_i;
    lrclkDac <= lrclk_i;

    dacSerial <= dacSerial_i;

    clocks: clk_wiz_v3_6
    port map
    (
        clk_in1 => clk,
        mclk => mclk_i,
        sclk => sclk_i,
        reset => reset
    );

    clocks2: i2sClocks
    port map
    (
        clk => sclk_i,
        lrclk => lrclk_i
    );      

    adc: i2sReceiver
    port map
    (
        serialClock => sclk_i,
      wordSelect => lrclk_i,
      serialData => adcSerial,
      lastSample => sample_i
    );

    dac: i2sTransmitter
    port map
    (
        serialClock => sclk_i,
      wordSelect => lrclk_i,
      serialData => dacSerial_i,
      lastSample => sample_i
    );



end Behavioral;
```

#### constrains-clean.ucf

```
CONFIG VCCAUX = "3.3" ;

NET "clk"           LOC = V10 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | PERIOD = 100MHz;
NET "reset"         LOC = C17  | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST | PULLUP;

NET "dacSerial" LOC = T11;
NET "sclkDac"       LOC = T10;
NET "lrclkDac"      LOC = V13;
NET "mclkDac"       LOC = V11;

NET "adcSerial" LOC = H17;
NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18; 
NET "lrclkAdc"      LOC = J18;
NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16;
```

## Build results

1. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to outputs (receiver), sythesis and implemetation are successful.
2. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to receiver's and transmitter's outputs, I get errors:

   ```
   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]: NET "sclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "sclkAdc"     LOC = H18;> [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "mclkAdc"     LOC = K16;> [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.
   ```
3. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to receiver's and transmitter's outputs and to additional divider used to generate LRCLK, I get errors:

   ```
   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]: NET "sclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "sclkAdc"     LOC = H18;> [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "mclkAdc"     LOC = K16;> [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   Done...

   Checking expanded design ...

   ERROR:NgdBuild:809 - output pad net 'sclkDac' has an illegal load:
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_0 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_1 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_2 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_3 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_4 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_5 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_6 with type FD
   ```
4. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to receiver's and transmitter's outputs,to additional divider used to generate LRCLK and to I2S modules in project, I get errors:

   ```
   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "sclkAdc"     LOC = H18;> [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "mclkAdc"     LOC = K16;> [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   WARNING:NgdBuild:1012 - The constraint <NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)] is overridden on the design object sclkDac by the
   constraint <NET "sclkDac"       LOC = T10;> [constrains-clean.ucf(8)].
   ```

To be honest, I spend a few days trying to solve it but with no luck. What should I do to succesfully connect clock divider from CORE Generator and build project without errors?

## EDIT:

Thanks to @Paebbels, warnings about `wordSelect` and `currentSampleIndex_i_5` are no longer occuring. Following his advices, I changed design as follows:

1. In constraints.ucf pin reset is assigned only to location and I/O standard and so does every other pin besides clk (i.e. `LOC = T10 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;`).
2. `currentSampleIndex` in both transmitter and receiver is now written as unsigned.
3. `currentSampleIndex` and every assignment or condition with it is trimmed to 5 bits
4. The condition in transmitter and receiver is now `if (wordSelect = (not lastWordSelect_i))`

#### Fatal errors

Errors and warnings occuring durign compilation are now as follow:

1. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to receiver's and transmitter's outputs and to additional divider used to generate LRCLK

   ```
   Clock Information:
   ------------------
   -----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------        -+
   Clock Signal                       | Clock buffer(FF name)             | Load  |
   -----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------+
   clocks/clk1obuf                    |         NONE(clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_0)| 7     |
   clocks/pll_base_inst/CLKOUT1       |         BUFG                              | 1     |
   clocks/pll_base_inst/CLKOUT0       |         BUFG                              | 1     |
   -----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------        -+
   INFO:Xst:2169 - HDL ADVISOR - Some clock signals were not
   automatically buffered by XST with BUFG/BUFR resources. Please use
   the buffer_type constraint in order to insert these buffers to the
   clock signals to help prevent skew problems.


   (...)

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18 |>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]: NET "sclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "sclkAdc"     LOC = H18 |> [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]: NET "sclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16 |>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "mclkAdc"     LOC = K16 |> [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   Done...

   Checking expanded design ...
   ERROR:NgdBuild:809 - output pad net 'sclkDac' has an illegal load:
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_0 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_1 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_2 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_3 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_4 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_5 with type FD,
   pin C on block clocks2/i2sClocksDivider_i_6 with type FD
   ```
2. When clock divider from CORE Generator is connected to receiver's and transmitter's outputs,to additional divider used to generate LRCLK and to I2S modules in project

   ```
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_0> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_0> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_1> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed :       <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_1> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_2> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_2> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_3> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_3> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_4> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_4> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/currentSampleIndex_us_5> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/currentSampleIndex_us_5> 
   INFO:Xst:2261 - The FF/Latch <adc/lastWordSelect_i> in Unit <box> is equivalent to the following FF/Latch, which will be removed : <dac/lastWordSelect_i> 

   (...)


   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "sclkAdc"     LOC = H18 |> [constrains-clean.ucf(13)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <NET "mclkAdc"       LOC = K16 |>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.

   WARNING:ConstraintSystem - A target design object for the Locate constraint
   '<NET "mclkAdc"     LOC = K16 |> [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]' could not be found
   and so the Locate constraint will be removed.

   ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - Constraint <IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(15)]: NET "mclkAdc" not found.  Please verify that:
   1. The specified design element actually exists in the original design.
   2. The specified object is spelled correctly in the constraint source file.


   WARNING:NgdBuild:1012 - The constraint <NET "sclkAdc"       LOC = H18 |>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)] is overridden on the design object sclkDac by the
   constraint <NET "sclkDac"       LOC = T10 |> [constrains-clean.ucf(8)].
   WARNING:NgdBuild:1012 - The constraint <IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;>
   [constrains-clean.ucf(13)] is overridden on the design object sclkDac by the
   constraint <IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33;> [constrains-clean.ucf(8)].
   ```

Comment: The top level vhdl file is missing. The error messages complain about missing or removed (optimized) signals.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Top module is added now.

Comment: Have you searched your synthesis reports for removed logic/pins? Are the pins present in the RTL schematic?

Comment: @Paebbels, when transmitter's and receiver's modules are connected, the warnings about unconnected pins are as follow: 
2 times WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <wordSelect> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected(...);

WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <currentSampleIndex_i_5> of sequential type is unconnected in block <i2sReceiver>;

WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <currentSampleIndex_i_5> of sequential type is unconnected in block <i2sTransmitter>.

Comment: Please extend your question with a new section on these *fatal* warnings, so everybody can find them. So why is `wordSelect` never used? Please see my extension in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pins in your top module disagree with the constraints file.

Answer (score 1):

**Error in UCF file:**

```
NET "reset" LOC = C17  | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST | PULLUP;
```

The pin `reset` is an input, so you shouldn't set a drive strength of `8 mA` and a slew rate, these constraints are for outputs. Please check your schematic, if the reset pin / wire has already a pullup resistor. If so don't enable the internal pullup in the IOB.

You should also extend all your lines with the appropriate I/O standard.

**Simplifying the VHDL code:**

```
currentSampleIndex_i <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(currentSampleIndex_i) + 1);
```

This line could be shortened if you declare `currentSampleIndex_i` as `UNSIGNED`.

- `USE`clause: `use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;` (already present in your code)
- Declaration: `signal currentSampleIndex_us : UNSIGNED(5 downto 0) := (others => '0');`
- Counting: `currentSampleIndex_us <= currentSampleIndex_us + 1;`
- Comparisons: `if (currentSampleIndex_us = 5) then`
- Type conversion: `currentSampleIndex_i <= std_logic_vector(currentSampleIndex_us)`

The `UNSIGNED` type is likely a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, but extended with *unsigned* arithmetic operations like add, sub, mult, ... .If you need *signed* (2s complement) arithmetic declare the signal as `SIGNED`.

**Input ... is never used**:

> WARNING:Xst:647 - Input <wordSelect> is never used. This port will be preserved and left unconnected(...);

So the synthesizer warns you, that the signal `wordSelect` is never used. But it is used in you code/process. How can it happen? For example, if the control flow never reaches the line `lastWordSelect_i <= wordSelect;`, than, wordSelect will never be used.

So why does the control flow never reach this line? Because the condition `(lastWordSelect_i = (not lastWordSelect_i))` can never be true. You could rewrite the condition to `(lastWordSelect_i != lastWordSelect_i)`.

*Solution*: Fix this condition.

**Node ... of sequential type is unconnected in block ...**:

> WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <currentSampleIndex_i_5> of sequential type is unconnected in block <i2sReceiver>
>   WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <currentSampleIndex_i_5> of sequential type is unconnected in block <i2sTransmitter>

Your signal `currentSampleIndex_i` has 6 bit. The synthesizer expands your vector to 6 separate wires named `currentSampleIndex_i_0` to `currentSampleIndex_i_5`. Bits 0 to 4 are used, but 5 is:

- unused or
- holds the same value in every cycle or
- does not matter in comparisons.

So let's look to the comparisons ...

```
-- condition 1 and 2
if ((currentSampleIndex_i             = "011100") or
    (currentSampleIndex_i             = "111100")) then
-- condition 3
     currentSampleIndex_i(4 downto 0) <  "11000"
```

As you can see, bit 5 does not matter.

---

I'll extend my answer if I find more faults ...